# How to print all commands from a subcommand in Go?

Tags: go

I'd like to make a subcommand in Golang that prints all parent commands. Example:

```
$ cli-tool list
Commands available:
- h, help for more info
- version for current version of tool
- list to list all commands
```

Current code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "flag"
)

func main() {
    version := flag.NewFlagSet("version", flag.ExitOnError)
    list := flag.NewFlagSet("list", flag.ExitOnError)

    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "version":
        version.Parse(os.Args[2:])
    case "list":
        list.Parse(os.Args[2:])
    }

    if version.Parsed() {
        fmt.Println("5e")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if list.Parsed() {
        flag.PrintDefaults()
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
$cli-tool list
$
```

(No commands print.)

I think this is pulling from the "list" command, not all the base commands. I'd expect it to print "version" and "list", but it doesn't print anything. Is there a way I can adjust this to make "PrintDefaults" always refer to the parent command?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `flag.PrintDefaults` refers to the flag singleton, ie `flag.CommandLine` variable https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#pkg-variables in your case you got to write it by your own. Maybe via a map. but i believe you  are reinventing the wheel. Github has some packages to deal with that.

Comment: Maybe you should use another package for doing this. The flag-package is just for very basic things. Maybe you should have a look at this: https://pkg.go.dev/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra